# How to place dependencies on a specific folder using bower?

Tags: javascript, bower, bower-install

I am using `bower` to import some libraries on my `Project` folder.

At the moment using `bower install` in `cd Project`, a folder `www/lib` is being installed in within my `Project` folder.

I need to get rid of `www/lib` and place all dependencies under `Project` folder.

How to achieve this

```
Project
      bower.json
```

---

I need this structure:

```
Project
      bower.json
      dojo
      dijit
      ...
```

---

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dojoBuild": "app.profile.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "dojo": "~1.10.2",
        "dijit": "~1.10.2",
        "dojox": "~1.10.2",
        "normalize-css": "~3.0.0",
        "put-selector": "~0.3.6",
        "util": "dojo-util#~1.10.2",
        "xstyle": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "directory": "",
    "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [bower docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/)

> Bower can be configured using JSON in a .bowerrc file. For example:

```
{
  "directory": "app/components/",  //set the directory you want here
  "analytics": false,
  "timeout": 120000,
  "registry": {
    "search": [
      "http://localhost:8000",
      "https://bower.herokuapp.com"
    ]
  }

}
```

> directory
>
> String
>
> The path in which installed components should be saved. If not
>   specified this defaults to bower_components.

```
"directory": "~/my-project/vendor"
```

Comment: Shouldn't you avoid answering since you already found a duplicate?

Comment: I probably should, but for completeness, I thought I would. I dont know the proper protocol in this sitch